# How Can I Present a Modal in Function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a google map project, I want to show location details with present a modal. I added delegate methods and I have didtap event, how can I present modal there ?

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State var showModal = false

   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView()
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Harita"))
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            DetailView()
        }
   }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**DetailView.swift**

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Inside Modal View")
                .padding()
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView()
    }
}
```

**MapView.swift**

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    let kMapStyle = "[" +
    "  {" +
    "    \"featureType\": \"poi\"," +
    "    \"elementType\": \"all\"," +
    "    \"stylers\": [" +
    "      {" +
    "        \"visibility\": \"off\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }" +
    "]"

    struct Markers {

    var latitude: Double?
    var longitude: Double?
    }


    let markers = [
        Markers(latitude: -33.8636005, longitude: 151.2114429),
        Markers(latitude: -33.863190, longitude: 151.209900),
        Markers(latitude: -33.8656308, longitude: 151.2116911),
        Markers(latitude: -33.8643534, longitude: 151.2117847)]


    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 0, longitude: 0, zoom: 16.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        do {
          mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(jsonString: kMapStyle)
        } catch {
          NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
        mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
        mapView.settings.rotateGestures = true
        mapView.settings.tiltGestures = true
        mapView.isIndoorEnabled = false

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {

        if let myLocation = locationManager.lastKnownLocation {
            mapView.animate(toLocation: myLocation.coordinate)
            print("User's location: \(myLocation)")
        }
        for mark in markers {
            let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mark.latitude!, longitude: mark.longitude!)
            marker.title = "Sydney"
            marker.snippet = "Australia"
            marker.map = mapView
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}

final class Coordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    var control: MapView

    init(_ control: MapView) {
        self.control = control
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print("You tapped")
        return false
    }
}
```

I want to show details like google maps application (bottom sheet). But I could not find any way to present modal inside of didTap method. Can you help me ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here;

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        window?.rootViewController?.present(UIHostingController(rootView: DetailView()), animated: true)
        return false
    }
```

Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Shall i open modal here?